# Swift NSSocket programming/python tutorial fix

Tags: python, swift, sockets, network-programming

I know next to nothing about Python but I am trying to follow a tutorial on NSSockets in swift; and that uses python. This is the python script. Script was in python2, but I have to run it under python 3.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class IphoneChat(Protocol):
def connectionMade(self):
    self.factory.clients.append(self)
    print("clients are ", self.factory.clients)

def connectionLost(self, reason):
    self.factory.clients.remove(self)

def dataReceived(self, data):
    a = data.split(':')
    print(a)
    if len(a) > 1:
        command = a[0]
        content = a[1]

        msg = ""
        if command == "iam":
            self.name = content
            msg = self.name + " has joined"

        elif command == "msg":
            msg = self.name + ": " + content
            print(msg)

        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.message(msg)

def message(self, message):
     self.transport.write(message + '\n')


factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
print("Iphone Chat server started")
reactor.run()
```

It works, but when I try and connect with my Swift code it sort of crashes with this message.

```
File "server.py", line 13, in dataReceived
a = data.split(':')
builtins.TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Complaining that the data I am sending it is in the wrong format; this is the swift code that sends the message.

```
func sayhello() {
    let response = String(format:"iam:brian")
    let dataToSend = [UInt8](response.utf8)
    outputStream?.write(dataToSend, maxLength: dataToSend.count)
}
```

How can I fix either the swift or the python? The tutorial I am trying to follow/translate is in.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Comment: Sounds like you're using python 3 for a python 2.x tutorial?

Comment: Yes, its python 2, and objective C; but I working in with python 3 and swift... and need some help tweeking this script.

Comment: This is a common python2 vs python3 issue. In python2, there was no real distinction between "bytes" and "character strings". python3 distinguishes. In python3, you need to `encode` in one direction and `decode` in the other. This answer has a good explanation of the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710178/when-to-use-unicodestring-and-string-encodeutf-8-in-python/26712007#26712007

Comment: Thank you Gil. I have have figured out the correct combination to find out what is happening, now I just need to figure out how the daft encode/unicode thing works in python if at all; I may just switch to 100% swift. Put the python back in the cupboard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076479/gil-hamilton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076479/gil-hamilton/%22Gil%20Hamilton%22) link I managed to work out what I am looking at. The solution. I am using the same swift code I posted here and I deleted the last section of the python. I am sending and receiving this.

```
Iphone Chat server started
clients are  [<__main__.IphoneChat object at 0x1035039e8>]
b'iam:brian'
```

Now I know where the issue lies, with the python I can find the answer! I basically deleted this in the python script.

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
a = data.split(':')
print(a)
if len(a) > 1:
    command = a[0]
    content = a[1]

    msg = ""
    if command == "iam":
        self.name = content
        msg = self.name + " has joined"

    elif command == "msg":
        msg = self.name + ": " + content
        print(msg)

    for c in self.factory.clients:
        c.message(msg)

def message(self, message):
 self.transport.write(message + '\n')
```

And replaced it with this ...

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    print(data)
    dumb=data.decode('utf8')
    print(dumb)
```

Its so easy its stupid ....